# Erasing smaller polygons within bigger in the same layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, polygon, geometry, overlapping-features, erase

I want to erase features by using PyQGIS. I have written this code. So far, it gives me the geometry of each feature polygon layer, but I don't know how to erase it through PyQGIS.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer() #get active layer
for f in layer.getFeatures():
  geom = f.geometry()
  print(geom.asPolygon()) #get polygon
```

[image]

As the picture suggested, a big polygon contains a small polygon. I want to erase all small polygons in that same layer so if I move a small polygon after erasing hallow will be shown in the big polygon.

Comment: How do you want to split it? With another layer?

Comment: @Freight_Train no within same layer

Comment: I dont want to create any other layer just want to split and hallow the layer. actually in layer there is a big polygon which includes small polygons. i want to split them

Comment: Do you want to split each feature or cut holes in the containing polygon with using the geometry of the smaller polygon?

Comment: split feaures work like cut. i want to retain splitted polygon.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume there is a polygon vector layer with several features within other features, see the image below.

[image: input]

Please pay attention, that bigger features do not contain holes.

[image: bigger_features]

Using the following code it is possible to delete features whose geometries are within the geometries of bigger features:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

layer.startEditing()

for feat1 in layer.getFeatures():
    geom1 = feat1.geometry()
    for feat2 in layer.getFeatures():
        geom2 = feat2.geometry()
        if geom2.within(geom1) and not geom1.equals(geom2):
            layer.deleteFeature(feat2.id())
            
layer.commitChanges()
```

then you can get the following output:

[image: result]